# In chart.js, how to know if a yAxes tick is bumping/rendering over/into another

Tags: javascript, canvas, chart.js

using chart.js version is 2.8.0 (finally updated it today ^_^)

Ive tried `autoSkip: true` and `autoSkipPadding: 10` but these yAxes tick values are not working for logarithmic scale

[image]

We cannot override the tick step value since I'm currently using a logarithmic yAxes

I know that I can use the `callback` function for the `yAxes` on chartjs's documentation to return either `null` or `undefined` to totally not render the y tick value but I would need to know if the positioning is touching another y tick bounds/bounding box, if you will, if I wanted to do that/before Im able to do that

I know its a problem, but canvas is not my strong suit - yet ;)

Ill keep digging and trying some things, but any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go into the chart.js library logic and add in my own custom modifications. I call my own function to return a boolean flag stating I should skip the current y axis to be drawn or not and I pass it the currentY value to use to draw and the previous y value used when it was drawn

this Chart.js library version is chartjs.2.2.2 and I edited and made these custom modifications within src/core/core.scale.js from the code in the following if statement around like lines 800 give or take a few hundred lines :p

```
if (optionTicks.display) {
    //...
}
```

Maybe that will help anyone else, good luck!

cheers